# problem with calculating all elements in array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM orders");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $cost= array_sum($row['cost']);
}
```

This is not working, I want to to calculate the sum of all elements but I get this error:

> Warning: array_sum() expects parameter
>   1 to be array, string given in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\falco\classes\controller.php
>   on line 303

Any idea how to calculate all the elements coming from mysql?

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: The reason your solution throws an error is that it appears that $row is an array (containing a single row from your table) and $row['cost'] is a single value. Also, you are attempting to sum a single row, therefore the result would be the value of the field `cost`. The answers provided below are reasonable options, especially the `select sum(cost) from foo...` mysql statement

Answer (score 2):

Why not let MYSQL handle it?

$query = $db->query("SELECT orders.*,SUM(cost) as sum_cost FROM orders");

Answer (score 2):

If its just a sum you want you can let the database do it for you:

```
 Select sum(cost) from orders
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM orders");
$cost = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $cost += $row['cost'];
}
```

Or from mysql:

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT sum(`cost`) as `cost` FROM orders");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $cost = $row['cost'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this should work:

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM orders");

$cost = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $cost += $row['cost'];
}
```

or even better

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT SUM(cost) FROM orders");
list($cost) = mysql_fetch_row($query);
```

Answer (score 1):

Really, it sounds like you just want the sum.

```
'SELECT SUM(cost) as sum_cost FROM ORDERS'
```